# Loading @ManyToOne associations with initial-data.yml

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am using initial-data.yml to import a set of sample data into my application running on Play 2.0.1.  I am trying to load members, schemes and memberships.  Members and Schemes are importing OK, but memberships (that has a foreign key to members and schemes) only ever imports the last entry in the list.

Here is my initial-data.yml file:

```
# Members

members:

 - !!models.Member
    email:      mark@zucker.com
    name:       Mark Zucker
    created:    null
    last_updated:  null

 - !!models.Member
    email:      vickysmith@email.com
    name:       Vicky Smith
    created:    null
    last_updated:  null

 - !!models.Member
    email:      sjones@yahoo.com
    name:       Simon Jones
    created:    null
    last_updated:  null

 - !!models.Member
    email:      steve@james.com
    name:       Steve James
    created:    null
    last_updated:  null

# Schemes

schemes:

 - !!models.Scheme
    id:         1
    name:       Walmart

 - !!models.Scheme
    id:         2
    name:       Amazon

 - !!models.Scheme
    id:         3
    name:       Outdoors Living

# Memberships

memberships:

 - !!models.Membership
    membership_id: 1234567890
    accrued:       2000
    balance:       1000
    joined_by:     !!models.Member
                     id:    1                
    scheme:        !!models.Scheme
                     id:    1

memberships:

 - !!models.Membership
    membership_id: 6543210000
    accrued:       10000
    balance:       10000
    joined_by:     !!models.Member
                     id:    2                
    scheme:        !!models.Scheme
                     id:    1
```

Here is the relevant parts of my model definitions:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import models.Membership;

@Entity
public class Member extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;         

@Required
public String email;        
public String name;         
public Date created;         
public Date last_updated;
```

Here is part of the scheme model:

```
@Entity
public class Scheme extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;
@Required
public String name;
```

Here's the membership model:

```
@Entity
public class Membership extends Model {

@Id
public Long membership_id;      

@Required
@ManyToOne              
public Member joined_by;        

@Required
@ManyToOne                  
public Scheme scheme;       

public Long accrued;        
public Long balance;
```

Here's the insert method in Global.java:

```
public static void insert(Application app) {
        Map<String,List<Object>> all = (Map<String,List<Object>>)Yaml.load("initial-data.yml");

        if(Ebean.find(Member.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
            Logger.info("Loading members from initial-data.yml");
                    Ebean.save(all.get("members"));
        }

        if(Ebean.find(Scheme.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
            Logger.info("Loading schemes from initial-data.yml");
                    Ebean.save(all.get("schemes"));
        }

        if(Ebean.find(Membership.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
            Logger.info("Loading memberships from initial-data.yml");
                    Ebean.save(all.get("memberships"));                
            }

        Logger.info("Loaded "+Ebean.find(Member.class).findRowCount()+" members");
        Logger.info("Loaded "+Ebean.find(Scheme.class).findRowCount()+" schemes");
        Logger.info("Loaded "+Ebean.find(Membership.class).findRowCount()+" memberships");
    }
```

I've switched logging on to count the number of rows inserted into each table, and here is the output:

```
DEBUG - select count(*) 
from member t0
INFO  - Loaded 4 members
DEBUG - select count(*) 
from scheme t0
INFO  - Loaded 3 schemes
DEBUG - select count(*) 
from membership t0
INFO  - Loaded 1 memberships
```

As you can see, all members and schemes are loaded, but only a single membership is loaded.  This is always the last one in the list (so membership 6543210000 in the initial-data.yml file above).  If I swap the entries around, it is still always the last one!

What do I need to change for this to load all of the memberships data in initial-data.yml?

Answer (score 3):

In initial-data.yml under # Memberships you have two 'memberships:' so it looks like the second definition is the one that gets processed.  remove the second membership

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle manytoone relationship in the yaml bootstrap files for ebean is by creating references.

Here is the object that you want to reference :

```
- !!models.User &ref
    mail:      b@b.fr
    firstName: bbb
    lastName:  BBB
```

The &ref annotation is an alias for the object referenced here.

Now you can reference it :

```
- !!models.book
    owner:        *ref
    title:        myBook
```

The *ref symbol stand for "the object associated with the reference ref". The owner of the book will be bbb !